# How to connect to the mongodb-cluster using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, x509, mongoengine

I'm build mongodb-cluster with replication and sharding. I'm set x509-based authentication.
I'm connect to database (mongos) by mongo as:

```
mongo admin --ssl --sslCAFile mongoCA.pem \
--sslPEMKeyFile client.pem -u user -p password --host my.host.com --port 27017
```

How do I connect to the cluster using the mongoengine?

I did not find the description of the connection options for the method **register_connection**:

```
def register_connection (alias, name = None, host = None, port = None,
                         read_preference = READ_PREFERENCE,
                         username = None, password = None, authentication_source = None,
                         ** Kwargs):
```

For example PyMongo provides the necessary options http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/authentication.html#mongodb-x509 but I need use mongoengine in existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked dokstring "register_connection" and I found:

```
:param kwargs: allow ad-hoc parameters to be passed into the pymongo driver
```

And I use this as:

```
import os
import ssl
from mongoengine import DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME, register_connection
from pymongo import ReadPreference

db_host = os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost')
db_port = int(os.getenv('DB_PORT', '27017'))
db_name = os.getenv('DB_DATABASE', 'mydatabase')

ssl_certfile = os.getenv('SSL_SERTFILE', 'client.pem')
ssl_cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
ssl_ca_certs = os.getenv('SSL_CA_CERTS', 'mongoCA.pem')

db_user = os.getenv('DB_USER', 'myUser')
db_pass = os.getenv('DB_PASS', '')

ssl_config = {
    'ssl': True,
    'ssl_certfile': ssl_certfile,
    'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl_cert_reqs,
    'ssl_ca_certs': ssl_ca_certs
}

register_connection(alias=DEFAULT_CONNECTION_NAME,
                    name=db_name,
                    host=db_host,
                    port=db_port,
                    username=db_user,
                    password=db_pass,
                    read_preference=ReadPreference.NEAREST,
                    authentication_source=db_name,
                    **ssl_config)
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoEngine is base on pymongo. A mongo_url like 'mongodb://user:passwd@ip:port,ip:port/db' work well in MongoEngine and Pymongo.

The code is like this:

```
from mongoengine import connect, Document, StringField

connect('mpc', host='mongodb://mpc:mpc@mongo-1:28010,mongo-2:28010,mongo-3:28010/mpc')

class User(Document):
    title = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)

print User.objects.count()
```

For more information: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html

Answer (score 1):

When using `mongoengine` connecting to [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/) cluster  you can use the following simplified function:

```
# Connect to, return database
def db_connect(database):
    db_uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    db = connect(database, host=db_uri)
    return db
```

Where the database variable is a string with the name of the database.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use `flask_mongoengine` here is the workable solution for an ssl certificate:

```
# config.py
import ssl


class Config(object):
    # some other settings
    # ...
    # db settings
    MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        'MONGODB_HOST': 'mongodb://username:password@host:port/db_name?replicaSet=rs_name&authSource=db_name',
        'MONGODB_SSL': True,
        'MONGODB_SSL_CERT_REQS': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        'MONGODB_SSL_CA_CERTS': '/path/to/ca/certificate.crt',
    }


# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = MongoEngine()
db.init_app(app)
```